# c#: Deployment.WindowsInstaller.BadQuerySyntaxException: SQL query syntax invalid or unsupported

Tags: c#, windows-installer

My program is a simple one.

What I want to achieve in this particular method-

1. Find total number of shortcuts
2. Delete document related shortcuts (i.e. .pdf, .txt, .chm)

I am using `Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller` to read through MSI files and create MST.

It is failing at below parts of code:

```
count = (int)database.ExecuteScalar("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Shortcut");
....
database.Execute("DELETE FROM Shortcut WHERE `Shortcut`.`Target` LIKE '%.chm'");
Console.WriteLine("chm deleted");
```

The error that I'm getting is:

> Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.BadQuerySyntaxException: SQL query syntax invalid or unsupported.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: @mjwills It gives same error. All other SQL statements are working fine. I'm having trouble with just these two. Instead of LIKE '%chm' if I give = '<FullName>' it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Installer SQL isn't the same as full SQL - it's a subset, and some things don't work. For example, using Select Count(*) doesn't work in my tests, so may need to iterate through them. Also "like" may not be supported.

Answer (score 0):

***Online***: As Phil states, **the MSI SQL syntax is a sub-set of normal SQL**. [**You can find information on the MSI SQL syntax online here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/sql-syntax).

---

***Offline***:  You can also find the [**`MSI SQL Syntax`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/sql-syntax) described in the **`msi.chm`** help file (Windows Installer SDK) which is installed with the [`Windows SDK`](https://developer.microsoft.com/nb-no/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) or the [`WiX toolset`](http://wixtoolset.org/) ([`download`](http://wixtoolset.org/releases/)).

Just search for the help file on disk - or find it in the WiX installation folder if you have **WiX** installed. The latter is probably much faster and easier than searching the SDK folders.